# Review failed in Windows Store for my appx package

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, desktop-bridge

I have sent a new version of my app to Windows app store for review.

This time the review has failed at this step:

--> App manifest resources tests

With this (strange) message:

-->E rror Found: The app resources validation test detected the following errors:
The "resources.pri" file must contain a resource map with a name that matches the package name "yyyyy.xxx.MyIpApp".

--> Manifest Resource Validation Test encountered error: hr = 0x80073B1F.

I don't understand this message because The package name is correct in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the local `WACK` test before you submitting the app to store? If not, please do the `WACK` test by following [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit-tests) firstly, and to see if you got the same errors.

According to  `App manifest resources tests` section of [Windows Desktop Bridge app tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-desktop-bridge-app-tests) tutorial, the corrective action for the above error message you mentioned should be as follows:

> You can get this error if the manifest changed and the name of the resource map in resources.pri no longer matches the package name in the manifest. In the actual message, {package full name} contains the package name that resources.pri must contain. To fix this, you need to rebuild resources.pri and the easiest way to do that is by rebuilding the app's package.

So that you could try to rebuild the app's package to solve the issue and do the `WACK` test again.

Comment: thanks for this infos. I have tested with WACK with no error. I have read too the tutorial (but after my post). Now i have re-created the app (and the manifest file) with Desktopappconverter utility. I think this can fix the issue. Today i will send the app to MS.....

Comment: Yes, i have re-created the appx file. Now the Windows Store accept my App. I think this was an issue about the manifest file.